# How I can auto scroll down when a new message is posted

Tags: javascript, html

I have this javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

$("#messages").load('ajax/chat/chat_load.php');
$("#msg").submit(function() {

    $.post("ajax/chat/chat_post.php", $("#msg").serialize(), function(data){

        $("#messages").append(data);

    });

    return false;
});

});
```

I have added `$("#messages").scrollTop($("#messages")[0].scrollHeight)`
 after append but when new messages is posted list is not autoscroll down.

This is the form:

```
<section class="chat-list">
    <ul class="list-group no-radius m-b-none m-t-n-xxs list-group-lg no-border">
       <div id="messages"></div>
         </li>
</ul>
</section>

    <form id="msg" action="" class="">
    <input class="form-control" name="messages" placeholder="Say something" type="text">               
     <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">SEND</button>
                              </form>
```

chat-list style:

```
.chat-list {
height: 300px;
overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done. For who want:

Adding id to section

```
<section id="chat" class="chat-list">
```

After that add

```
$("section#chat").scrollTop($("section#chat")[0].scrollHeight)
```

After append